# Spring Data Transaction Control

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

The question is about using multiple transaction in crudrepository, jparepository ext. In my project, there are two entities. RequestEntity and SendingMailEntity. WorkFlow in my method:

1) save RequestEntity ,

2) send informationService(it is an rest service that purchased by us. we can't control its any exception.)

3) save SendingMailEntity.

When we have an exception on number 2 or 3, we lost requestEntity because of rollback that is controlled by spring jpa.

The records of requestEntity are never to be lost.

```
@Transactional
public RequestEntity create(RequestEntity entity) {

    entity=requestRepository.save(entity);
    sendMail(entity);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public SendingMailEntity sendMail(RequestEntity entity) {

         /*
          *
          */
   informationService(entity.*,*,*);
         /*
          *
          */

     sendingMailRepository.save(sendingMailEntity);
}
```

This code block is not working. When sendMail has an error, RequestEntity is not saving.

Comment: If you can't control  'informationService' then why to include this in transaction.      If the whole process is not atomic then separate the failing code out of transaction or handle the exception properly. Have you tried Propagation=NOT_SUPPORTED

Comment: i tried it and it doesn't work. Actually  it is about out old habits. When using hibernate session, we can commit or rollback on line where we want. I can't control spring data.

Answer (score 1):

Handle all exceptions inside `sendMail`,  don't let it throw back to the calling function.

also you can try moving `sendMail` into a new public class with `override` if the exception handling alone doesn't work